# header, stylesheet not being read

Tags: theme-development, headers, css

I'm working on a theme that doesn't seem to be reading the header and/or stylesheet. All of the code seems to check out correctly, so I'm a little confused as to why this is happening. Perhaps I've overlooked something. If you look at the [live site](http://blog.christaandivy.com/), you can see that the loop/index.php is showing, but no header.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></h1>
        </div><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SITE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- end nav -->
    </div><!-- end header -->
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php get_sidebar(); ?> 

<div id="blog">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>  
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
        <div class="post" id="post-<!--?php the_ID(); ?-->">
    <div class="post_meta">
        <h2><a href="<!--?php the_permalink() ?-->" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
            <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p class="post_date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p>
    </div><!-- end blog_meta -->
    <div class="post">
        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/dots_small.png" class="divider" alt="post divider">
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- end post -->
    <div class="pagination">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>  
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
    </div>

     <?php else : ?>  
        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>  
        <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>  
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>  
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end blog -->

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: live site URL broken

Comment: @GhostToast Sorry about that, should be fixed now.

Comment: Something is badly broken. Disable your plugins. Use the Twenty Twelve. Do you still have the problem? Are you sure that `index.php` is the file being used? Those functions need to be in most of your theme templates-- `single.php`, `archive.php`, etc.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I assumed `index.php` was being used, but it appears `home.php` was being used instead. Copy/pasted all `index.php` content to `home.php`- everything works perfectly now. Thank you.

Comment: @user1255049 : My answer is correct, then? You were not using `get_header` where you needed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your theme template file(s) are not using [`get_header`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header), which is the function that loads your `header.php`. If so, you will need to add `get_header();` to the top of each of your template files.

My guess is that your theme template files are missing [`get_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) also as nothing that would normally be in that file, such as `</body>` or `</html>`, is printing either.

Comment: It is definitely there, I've edited the original post to show index.php